# System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed' In my ASP.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a model:

```
public class Checkout
{
    public string CheckoutId { get; set; }

    public List<CheckoutItem> CheckoutItems { get; set; }

}
```

And I am trying to add methods to the Object while respecting POCOs. So I added A repository:

```
    public class CheckoutRepository : ICheckoutRepository
    {
        private readonly AppDbContext _appDbContext;
        private readonly Checkout _checkout;

        public CheckoutRepository(AppDbContext appDbContext, Checkout checkout)
        {
            _appDbContext = appDbContext;
            _checkout = checkout;

        }

        public void AddItem(unitItem item, int amount)
        {
              //Removed for brevity 
        }

        public void ClearCheckout()
        {
           //Details removed for brevity
        }

        public Checkout GetCart(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {   
          //Details removed for brevity
        }

        public List<CheckoutItem> GetCheckoutItems()
        {
            //Details removed for brevity
        }

        public decimal GetCheckoutTotal()
        {
           //Details removed for brevity
        }

        public decimal RemoveItem(unitItem item)
        {
           //Details removed for brevity
        }
```

And an interface to the Repository

```
public interface ICheckoutRepository
    {
         Checkout GetCart(IServiceProvider serviceProvider);

        void AddItem(unitItem item, int amount);

        decimal RemoveItem(unitItem item);

        List<CheckoutItem> GetCheckoutItems();

        void ClearCheckout();

        decimal GetCheckoutTotal();
    }
```

I, of course, add this to the startup file.

`services.AddTransient<ICheckoutRepository, CheckoutRepository>();`

But when I run the application I get the error

> System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be
> constructed'

And 2 inner exceptions

1:

> InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service
> descriptor 'ServiceType: BataCMS.Data.Interfaces.ICheckoutRepository
> Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType:
> BataCMS.Data.Repositories.CheckoutRepository': Unable to resolve
> service for type 'BataCMS.Data.Models.Checkout' while attempting to
> activate 'BataCMS.Data.Repositories.CheckoutRepository'.

And 2:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
> 'BataCMS.Data.Models.Checkout' while attempting to activate
> 'BataCMS.Data.Repositories.CheckoutRepository'

Could really use some insight into this problem.

Comment: You are passing `Checkout checkout` in constructor, so you need either remove it from there or register it in the DI container.

Comment: Please check this article i facing this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74051242/dbinizializer-register-in-program-in-net6-core-6-0-9

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When you look at your `CheckoutRepository` constructor, you'll see that you're injecting an instance of a `Checkout` class. ASP.NET doesn't know where to search for an instance of that class to inject, so you have to register it in your DI container.

Add this to your Startup file:

```
services.AddTransient<Checkout>(new Checkout());
```

This is a little bit different type of registering. Instead of depending on abstraction, you're depending on a concrete implementation of `Checkout` class. I've passed a default, parameterless constructor to the above example, but you can pass any other constructor to it, or (to depend on an abstraction) just create the `ICheckout` interface and register just like you registered the `ICheckoutRepository`:

```
services.AddTransient<ICheckout, Checkout>();
```

More on DI can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

I also explore the practical approach to it in [this video](https://youtu.be/lSUGTB8VVNw)

Comment: Much appreciated thank you for the solution and explanation, just to clarify about the DI, Is it bad practice to inject the concrete class. Do I have to have some level abstraction using the `ICheckout` interface. But otherwise the solution works fine. Thanks again.

Comment: Hey Paul. No problem. Think about it this way: One day, you decide to add another checkout method, but your `ICheckoutRepository` only accepts one type of checkout (the concrete `Checkout` class) and the inner workings of any type of `ICheckoutRepository` (there can be many since it's an interface) depend on that class, so adding another one may become painful. If you introduce the `ICheckout` interface, you'll be able to construct that repo with any implementation of `ICheckout`. It also comes in handy when mocking while testing. Read up on dependency inversion principle :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you missing?

```
services.AddTransient<ICheckout, Checkout>();
```

Hope I helped.

Answer (score 1):

This was because I declared in IRepo as `IEnumerable` and passed a list from repo.

Fixing this has fixed my issues

Answer (score 0):

Also this type error occur when Context class used deependency injection

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).